# XConnect Exception When Using Azure SQL Server

Tags: xconnect

I restored my local Sitecore databases to Azure SqlServer.
And then i tried to make my local Sitecore 9 instance to connect to SQL Server database on Azure (i changed connection string to connect to databases on Azure).
The local website  http://mylocalinstance/sitecore worked well but i had a problem with xconnect and the Sitecore Reporting Service didn't work.
Here is the exception i saw in xconnnect log :

***2018-08-15 10:33:14.870 +07:00 [Error] XConnect Exception Logger LogAsync()
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'InteractionsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> System.ArgumentException: Type 'Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Controllers.InteractionsController' does not have a default constructor
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.DependencyInjection.WebApiServiceControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()***

Does anyone know what is the problem with it ?

Comment: OMG. It was my fault. The connection string to messaging db was wrong